# A truely custom login page?

Tags: customization, login, wp-login-form

I don't want to use a plugin for this one and i would like to know how i can use a custom form for WP login. I made a form with bootstrap and i added the form action and two hidden fields but it doesn't work

```
 <form name="loginform" id="loginform" class="form-signin login_form" action="<?php echo esc_url( wp_login_url() ); ?>" method="post">
.......

<input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="http://localhost/mydomain.dev/_site/wp-admin/<?php //echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ?>" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="testcookie" value="1" />
```

Or should i let this go and alter wp-login.php with hook and filters???

Any tips?

Comment: have you read [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form)?

Comment: I always find this tutorial to be a good reference point to make a completely bespoke login form: http://digwp.com/2010/12/login-register-password-code/ It's not a complete and concise answer to your question but hopefully it will get you going in the right direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Tomas Cot says, this page has everything you're looking for:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form

Specifically, this section is what you're looking for:

**Make a Custom Login Page**

> So far you've seen how to customize WordPress' built-in login page.
>   You can also create your own custom login Page by using the
>   wp_login_form function in one of your WordPress Theme's Page
>   Templates:

```
<?php wp_login_form(); ?>
```